# use of **and** operator within an **if statement**

Tags: delphi, if-statement, and-operator

I was directed to this website by a friend.

I am trying to use `and` in Delphi, but I seem to be doing something wrong. Is there something you need to put in uses?

I have the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
a,b:string;
begin
a:=edit1.Text;
b:=edit2.Text;

if a=abc and b=def then
showmessage(a+b);

end;
```

I get an error at the second = sign

Comment: A hint for future questions: When you say "I get an error", you need to say *what* the error is, so we'll know what to look for more easily. Remember, we can't see your screen from here. :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You have to put some parentheses to change the operator precedence:

```
  if (a=abc) and (b=def) then
```

Operator `and` precedes `=` so the construction without parenthesis is understood as
`a=(abc and b=def)` which produces the syntax error.

Comment: "and I need to write more characters to be submitted" <- haha :D

Comment: Also abc and def must be declared, if it's string values(not variables) have to be wrapped with quotes 'abc' and 'def'

Comment: @Daniel, I removed the sentence you cited, and completed my answer, to be (trying) more explanatory

Comment: Isn't it a=(abc and b)=def, rather than a=(abc and b=def)?

Answer (score 11):

`and` has a higher precedence than `=`. So `if a=abc and b=def then` becomes `if a=(abc and b)=def then`, which is not valid. So write it like `if (a=abc) and (b=def) then`.

Answer (score 8):

The **Operator Precedence** rules for Delphi are tripping you up. There are four levels.

1. @, NOT
2. *, /, div, mod, and, shl, shr, as
3. +, -, or, xor
4. =, <>, <, >, <=, >=, in, is

In your example the AND comparison will take place first unless you use brackets to force the equality comparisons to be done first.

[Expressions (Delphi) - Operator Precedence](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE/en/Expressions_%28Delphi%29#Operator_Precedence)

Answer (score 2):

Surely there are apostrophes missing from the strings - the statement should be

> if (a = 'abc') and (b = 'def') then ...

Comment: It's just an example, the problem is not about the apostrophes. `abc` and `def` are just variables.